# Filtering at the client side in hornetq

Tags: jms, hornetq

I have a server which is posting messages into one queue (Resides on server side) & many receivers....

I want every receiver or client should access that queue & receive the messages based on their How can I achieve it using `HornetQ JMS API`

Answer (score 0):

Just create the consumers using a filter...

However the best would be to use pub&sub, and each subscription using a different filter.

Comment: Now,I have 2 client Consumers which are asynchronously listening to HornetQ server.After client consumer listener 1 receives a message from HornetQ server, while processing this message if it gets crashed then I want client consumer listener 2 should pick that message and process it immidietely..... how can i acheive this...(forgive me if i am asking silly question since im new to hornetq)......

Comment: That seems another question? what's the relation to the first question?

Comment: I will answer your question if you open a new one.. that's not related to the first one at all. and BTW: you should accept the answers you get if they help you.